# std::map with non-unique key ordering but unique comparison

Tags: c++, stl, key, strict-weak-ordering

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>


struct Key{
    int attr1, attr2;
    Key(int attr1, int attr2) : attr1(attr1), attr2(attr2) {}

    friend bool operator== (const Key& s1, const Key& s2);
    friend bool operator< (const Key& s1, const Key& s2);
};

bool operator== (const Key& s1, const Key& s2){
    return ((s1.attr1 == s2.attr1) && (s1.attr2 == s2.attr2));
}

bool operator< (const Key& s1, const Key& s2){
    return (s1.attr1 < s2.attr1);
}

int main(void){
    std::map<Key, int> mmap;
    mmap.insert(std::make_pair(Key(10, 10), 5));
    mmap.insert(std::make_pair(Key(10, 20), 5));
    std::cout << mmap.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `1` where I would expect it to be `2`. This seems to be due to only `attr1` being compared in the `operator<`. However if I am correct, the comparison does not have to be a strong ordering, but rather having a weak ordering is sufficient. Is there some other bug here or do I have to define an `operator<` for which

> `Key1 !< Key2 && Key2 !< Key1` implies that `Key1 == Key2`

holds true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::map` does not use `operartor ==` at all when comparing elements.  By default, and in this case, it uses `std::less` which uses your `operator <`.  Since your `operator <` only compares `attr1`, and both objects have the same `attr1`, the are considered equivalent and thus you only have one object in the map.

To fix this you need to check both members and you can use the [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) trick to make a tuple that does this for you like

```
bool operator< (const Key& s1, const Key& s2){
    return std::tie(s1.attr1, s1.attr2) < std::tie(s2.attr1, s2.attr2);
}
```

---

Another option is to use a `std::unordered_map` which uses a hashing algorithm and an equality operator.  Using that you can hash `attr1` only, but have the equality operator check both `attr1` and `attr2` to make sure a true duplicate is not added.

Answer (score 0):

> if I am correct, the comparison does not have to be a strong ordering, but rather having a weak ordering is sufficient.

You're correct.

> The output is 1 where I would expect it to be 2.

You would expect wrongly because according to the weak ordering relation that you provided, those keys are considered equal.

> Is there some other bug here

No.

> do I have to define an `operator<` for which
>
> ```
> Key1 !< Key2 && Key2 !< Key1 implies that Key1 == Key2
> ```
>
> holds true?

If you want the operation to produce an ordering where keys are considered equal if and only if `Key1 == Key2` then yes, you do need to define such operator.

Or you could use a multi-map which may contain non-unique keys.